# How to create a clean, straight drop shadow?

Tags: photoshop-effects, drop-shadow

I've been messing around in Photoshop trying to re-create this nice effect. Does anyone know how to achieve a straight shadow like this?

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Give your icon a drop shadow.

   - Opacity around `25%`
   - Distance: `0`
   - Spread: `0`
   - Size: `250` (this is the max Photoshop will allow)
   - Click `OK`
2. Now turn this shadow into a layer (right click on the 'effect' lext to the layer in the Layers panel and click `Create Layer`
3. Now for the tricky bit – select the Polygonal Lasso Tool (`L`) and, holding down `Shift`, draw a selection box from the bottom-left of your icon to the bottom-right of your artboard, at 45 degrees, connecting back up to the top-right of your ocon, also at 45 degrees. There *must* be an easier way to do this – I'll edit this answer when I figure it out.
4. Select your 'Drop Shadow' layer and, in the Layers panel, click `Add a mask` to mask the shadow.

Alternatively, download one of these Photoshop plugins:

- http://graphicburger.com/long-shadow-generator/
- http://graphicriver.net/item/3d-long-shadows-generator-photoshop-action-set/5126534

I reckon that's cheating though – the best thing about Photoshop is seeing something you like and figuring out how to do it yourself!

Comment: Nice answer, but could you post this on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/how-to-make-a-graphic-with-long-shadow instead

Comment: @Ryan no worries, will do.